# Run cron in centOS as user process, not daemon

Tags: ubuntu, centos, cron, docker

According to [this site](http://www.ekito.fr/people/run-a-cron-job-with-docker/), an easy way to set up a scheduled task in a single Docker container is to create a single crontab that runs your task, and then invoke it as the last Docker `CMD` with the line `CMD cron`.

This seems to be an Ubuntu-only trick, as CentOS 7 reports `cron: command not found` if you create a similar Docker container with CentOS 7.

Is there a way to do this with CentOS, or, failing that, a better simple way to do schedule a single task in a CentOS Docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a C7 system to hand but on Fedora the cron daemon is called `crond` and lives in /usr/sbin. Perhaps you can figure it out from that. (it's easy)

Comment: You have to install the cronie package